# Debian squeeze - Unable to upgrade bash

Tags: debian, bash, debian-squeeze, maintenance

I'm trying to upgrade bash so its not vulnerable.

I tried Sources List Generator for Debian. But `libtinfo5` is stopping me from upgrading bash. I could not find older version (due to source list issue) of `libtinfo5` to see if could install it.

sources.list

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main



root@server:~# apt-get install --only-upgrade bash                                                                                                                        Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdpkg-perl bzip2 libmpfr4 fakeroot libalgorithm-merge-perl
  linux-kbuild-2.6.32 linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common libcloog-isl4
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libgomp1 libtimedate-perl cpp libgmp3c2 dpkg-dev
  wwwconfig-common gcc-4.3-base cpp-4.3 cpp-4.4 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  binutils javascript-common make libmpc3 libisl10 libjs-mootools
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libtinfo5
Suggested packages:
  bash-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtinfo5
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bash
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 316 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,725 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,806 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libtinfo5 bash
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/main libtinfo5 amd64 6.0+20161126-1 [                                                                                                  299 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable/main bash amd64 4.4-5 [1,427 kB]
Fetched 1,725 kB in 0s (3,319 kB/s)
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 36165 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libtinfo5 (from .../libtinfo5_6.0+20161126-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libtinfo5_6.0+20161126-1_amd64.de                                                                                                  b (--unpack):
 triggers ci file contains unknown directive `activate-noawait'
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libtinfo5_6.0+20161126-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

apt-cache policy output

```
root@server:~# apt-cache policy bash
bash:
  Installed: 4.1-3
  Candidate: 4.1-3
  Version table:
 *** 4.1-3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: You're mixing different Debian suites, this is not supported. Upgrade the whole system at least to wheezy, which is oldoldstable. jessie is oldstable, stretch is stable currently.

Comment: squeeze is end of life, see [this](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS). You either have to compile for yourself, which I wouldn't recommend, or upgrade to a supported suite.

Comment: Please show `apt-cache policy bash`.

Comment: Added that in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

- Do `wget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-archive/20160313T130328Z/debian/pool/main/b/bash/bash_4.1-3%2Bdeb6u2_amd64.deb` (assuming `amd64` is your architecture)
- After you've downloaded the file, run `dpkg -i bash_4.1-3+deb6u2_amd64.deb` (as root / via `sudo`)

**Seriously:** Upgrade this system, or take if offline.